# why am i getting this error using ffmpeg while decoding m3u8?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode a .m3u8 to mp4 using ffmpeg, but keep getting this error message:

> Error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #0:0
> https://....../audio.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input.

This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y -f hls -i https://www.video-cdn.com/video/encrypt/7b35e1550e7dac1fa9d6f34eb0b55148/R915dD-90d3ac3f-48d9-4da1-84d4-d354a7ed03de/90d3ac3f-48d9-4da1-84d4-d354a7ed03de/audio.m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb,dump_extra -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -map 0 -c copy -flags +global_header -max_interleave_delta 0 -f mp4 test.mp4
```

[cmdExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh9CS.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: @Adrian Mole I’m getting the same or arrow for a playlist that is definitely not encrypted

Answer (score 3):

The HLS stream is encrypted. You can see this because of the following line in the m3u8 playlist file:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="blob:https://www.video-cdn.com/90d3ac3f-48d9-4da1-84d4-d354a7ed03de",IV=0xa2dccda29716795b6a22bec559144723
```

Since the URI is with the Blob-Prefix, FFmpeg can not decrypt the stream, because this blob is only valid where you have received this URL (e.g. your browser).

To solve this, you need to manually download the m3u8 playlist file to your local drive, download also the AES-128 key manually, modify the playlist and pass this into FFmpeg. You can find a short tutorial [here](https://idof.medium.com/download-and-decrypt-aes-128-m3u8-playlists-495c12d6543a).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give that a try.